# Target inline JSON using jQuery .getJSON or similar method

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, getjson, associative

I am attempting to get data from an inline array wrapped in a `<script>` tag using jQuery's `.getJSON` method. As far as I am reading in documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), `.getJSON` requires a URL and external file to call from.

`$.getJSON('items.js', function(data) {});`

How would I use either this method or another one to specifically target an inline array (without an external file), such as the one below:

```
  <script type="application/json">   
   {
    "items": {
        "blue": {
          "a": "a",
          "b": "b",
          "c": "c"
        }
     }
   }
  </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to change the contents of the script tag?  `var myJson = ...;`?

Comment: Why would you store the JSON this way? Since it is hard-coded, why not just hard-code it in your script like: `var myVar={"items":...` ?

Comment: It's not hardcoded. I am writing it using ``echo json_encode($Array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)``

Comment: Doesn't seem clean to wrap the PHP echo'd array with a var xyz=. If there's no option for this I will do it, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put JSON by itself in a script tag, it has to be valid Javascript statements. Assign the JSON to a variable name:

```
<script>
var data = {
    "items": {
        "blue": {
          "a": "a",
          "b": "b",
          "c": "c"
        }
     }
};
<script>
```

Then the rest of your code can use `data` to access the value.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to store this data into a JavaScript object.

Do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($dataArray, JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;
</script>
```